# Android Studio How to properly put two views on top of each other?

Tags: java, android

I have a frame layout, in which I have a custom view and an ImageView. They are supposed to be exactly on top of each other.

My current xml code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        android:contentDescription="@string/camera"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <com.example.user.candleclub.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/DrawView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawviewshape"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This, as also shown in the design tab, should make both the CircleImageView and DrawView one on another. But when I run it, it puts the CircleImageView a bit below the DrawView. How can I fix this? I tried playing with the layout margin but it didn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: put in two different framelayout.

Comment: FrameLayouts are for displaying a single item, try using a RelativeLayout instead